# search name in text (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Any help will be appreciated: I just can't move on before I figure out what I'm doing wrong..

I'm searching for a name in some text with a `for` loop then trying to push those letters into an array. For some reason it's not pushing, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.. still a newb.. thx for the help!

```
var text = "Code it out bro, it will just get Zane Zane Zane better 
from here, especially after your familiar with the various 
frameworks..yeah man...";
var hits = [ ];
var nameZane = "Zane";
for (i=0; i < text.length; i++) 
if (i === "Z"){
    for (j=i; j < nameZane.length + i; j++){
    hits.push(text[j])}
}

if (hits.length === 0){
    console.log("Couldn't find " + nameZane)}
else{
    console.log(hits)}
```

Comment: why bother doing this much. Just use regex for this

Comment: Will `i === "Z"` ever be _true_?

Comment: It should be `text[i] === "Z"`

Answer (score 0):

Is not `i` its a `text[i]` use this if condition like this `if (text[i] === "Z") {`

```js
var text = "Code it out bro, it will just get Zane Zane Zane better from here, especially after your familiar with the variousframeworks..yeah man...";
var hits = [];
var nameZane = "Zane";
for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
  if (text[i] === "Z") {
    for (j = i; j < nameZane.length + i; j++) {
      hits.push(text[j])
    }
  }

if (hits.length == 0) {
  console.log("What the f*** man?")
} else {
  console.log(hits)
}
```

Comment: Just a minor optimisation. After `for` inside `if`, you can do `i+=nameZane.length`. That will remove unwanted iterations

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code:
`if (i === "Z")` to

```
if (text.charAt(i) == 'Z')
```

AND

```
hits.push(text[j])
```

to

```
hits.push(text.charAt(j));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /Zane/g,
str = "Code it out bro, it will just get Zane Zane Zane better from here, especially after your familiar with the various frameworks..yeah man...";
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    console.log("match found at " + match.index);
}
```